# Quiero hacer un UPDATE a esta consulta POSTGRESQL

Tags: base-de-datos, postgresql

En primer lugar agradecer de antemano a quien me brinde su comentario.

Estoy trabajando con dos tablas: ***PACIENTE*** y ***DETALLEHISTORIA*** relacionadas por el campo **CODHIST**, en la tabla **PACIENTE** tengo datos duplicados con el mismo **NOMBRE y DNI**, pero el **CODHIST** no se repite. En la tabla ***DETALLEHISTORIA*** se incluyen los detalles de la consulta de un paciente y los mismos se identifican por su **CODHIST** que se autogenera cuando creas un nuevo paciente. Por ejemplo: en ***DETALLEHISTORIA*** tengo 5 registros de un mismo paciente, 3 de esos registros con el **CODHIST** 3233 y 2 registros con el **CODHIST** 101 (los 5 registros pertenecen al mismo paciente) debo hacer un UPDATE en DETALLEHISTORIA donde los 5 registros tomen el CODHIST 101.

Estoy buscando hacer un UPDATE a partir de esta QUERY:

```
SELECT d.codhist
FROM paciente p, detallehistoria d 
WHERE p.codhist = d.codhist AND p.cedula IN (SELECT cedula
FROM paciente
GROUP BY cedula HAVING COUNT(*) > 1) ORDER BY d.codhist
```

Estuve intentando algo así pero me tira un error de sintaxis:

```
UPDATE codhist SET MIN(codhist) WHERE codhist IN (SELECT d.codhist
FROM paciente p, detallehistoria d 
WHERE p.codhist = d.codhist AND p.cedula IN (SELECT cedula
FROM paciente
GROUP BY cedula HAVING COUNT(*) > 1) ORDER BY d.codhist)
```

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: Traduce esto por favor, o explícalo con un ejemplo gráfico: *La idea principal es que en la columna codhist actualice el valor actual por el valor mínimo que consiga la consulta SELECT*. No se entiende lo que quieres realmente y ten cuidado, si hablamos de datos en producción una consulta mal escrita puede crear un desastre en los datos, conviene hacer pruebas en pequeños set de datos aislados, no los reales. Más bien alégrate de que la consulta no funciona, porque no parece ser lo que has dicho en la pregunta... Es un poco confuso todo, conviene que aclares con un ejemplo.

Comment: Hola, gracias por tu pronta respuesta. Estoy trabajando con un Backup de la db de forma local, no afecta los datos en producción. Tengo dos tablas: PACIENTE y DETALLEHISTORIA relacionadas por el campo CODHIST, en la tabla PACIENTE tengo datos duplicados con el mismo NOMBRE y DNI, pero el CODHIST no se repite. En la tabla DETALLEHISTORIA tengo registros del mismo paciente pero por ejemplo: 3 de esos registros con el CODHIST 3233 y 2 registros con el CODHIST 101 (los 5 registros pertenecen al mismo paciente) debo hacer un UPDATE en DETALLEHISTORIA donde los 5 registros tomen el CODHIST 101.

Comment: Hola, por favor las aclaraciones sobre la pregunta es mejor que las pongas en la pregunta, allí tienes espacio para explayarte, no escatimes en todo aquello que ayude a entender el contexto. Pulsa en [edit] y completa la pregunta.

Comment: Gracias @A.Cedano, he actualizado la pregunta, espero se entienda. Mis disculpas .

Comment: Ahora se entiende un poco mejor, pero queda algo que no está claro, en `DETALLEHISTORIA` cada paciente se identifica por los campos `NOMBRE` y `DNI`, o sólo por el `DNI` o por ninguno de los dos?

Comment: @A.Cedano Creo que ahora si =)

Comment: No, aún no entiendo. ¿Cómo sabes que el codhist `101` y el `3233` pertenecen al mismo paciente? En preguntas de este tipo conviene poner la estructura de las tablas. Fíjate el rato que llevo tratando de *adivinar* el contexto. Considera que no estamos en tu mente ni frente a tu pantalla, no estamos viendo lo que intentas hacer.

Comment: He agregado 3 fotos que explican un poco mas la situación, disculpa por no ser muy claro.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Puedes resolverlo siguiendo la siguiente lógica:

Dentro de una sub-consulta, obtienes el menor `codhist` (le he dado el alias `mincode`), y obtienes además una lista de los `codhist` usando `ARRAY_AGG` (le he dado el alias `groupP`), luego, por fuera, seteas en `detallehistoria` el valor obtenido en `mincode` y para comparar quienes tienen el mismo `codhist` en `pacientes` usas la lista obtenida en `groupP`.

Observa que en la sub-consulta, en el `GROUP BY` he puesto sólo el `dni` por asumir que ese valor es único, si debe ir también el `nombre` lo agregas simplemente.

Te dejo un fiddle funcionando. Tuve que reproducir el problema. Guarda el enlace a ese sitio, te ayudará y nos ayudará si planteas las preguntas partiendo de un ejemplo mínimo y verificable, eso vale  más que mil imágenes:

**Schema (PostgreSQL v9.4)**

```
CREATE TABLE paciente (
  codhist int,
  nombre varchar(250),
  dni varchar(20)
);

INSERT INTO paciente (codhist,nombre,dni) VALUES
    (101,'Pedro','P0001'),
    (3233,'Pedro','P0001'),
    (102,'Marta','M0002'),
    (999,'Marta','M0002'),
    (104,'Juan','J0003');

CREATE TABLE detallehistoria (
  codhist int
);

INSERT INTO detallehistoria (codhist) VALUES 
    (101),
    (104),
    (3233),
    (104),
    (104),
    (888),
    (999);
```

---

**Query #1**

```
UPDATE detallehistoria 
    SET codhist = p.mincode 
FROM 
    (
        SELECT 
            MIN(codhist) as mincode, 
            ARRAY_AGG(codhist) as groupP
        FROM paciente
        GROUP BY dni
    )AS p
WHERE codhist = ANY(p.groupP);
```

There are no results to be displayed.

---

**Query #2**

```
SELECT * FROM detallehistoria;
```

| codhist |
| --- |
| 888 |
| 101 |
| 104 |
| 101 |
| 104 |
| 104 |
| 102 |

---

**Query #3**

```
SELECT 
    p.codhist, 
    p.nombre, 
    p.dni 
FROM paciente p
    INNER JOIN detallehistoria d ON p.codhist=d.codhist
GROUP BY p.codhist,p.nombre,p.dni
ORDER BY p.codhist;
```

| codhist | nombre | dni |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 101 | Pedro | P0001 |
| 102 | Marta | M0002 |
| 104 | Juan | J0003 |

---

[View on DB Fiddle](https://www.db-fiddle.com/)

Comment: Gracias por toda tu ayuda, ejecuté la query y me está arrojando este error "SQL Error [23505]: ERROR: llave duplicada viola restricción de unicidad «pk_detallehistoria» será porque codhist es pk en ambas tablas?

Comment: @JoseMachuca edita la pregunta y coloca la estructura de ambas tablas, incluyendo sus llaves primarias, sus índices únicos si los tienen, sus relaciones de llave foránea, etc. Es viendo eso como podremos saber por qué no admite la actualización.